# Dynamic content of og:title Facebook meta tag

Tags: php, session, facebook-opengraph

I use session values to set the content of facebook meta tag :

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php print $_GET['p']; ?>"/>
```

when I view source of the website the html appears like this :

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Alex Atalla"/>
```

which means it is successfully filled the value of session value in the content of title meta tag.

But when I use facebook debugger it says that :

```
Object Missing a Required Value:    Object at URL 'http://www.palestinianz.com/' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.
```

what is the problem ?

Comment: when I test the url using facebook debugger :https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Just viewing the source of palestinianz.com, the title tag is there, but there's no value present on the homepage

Comment: @DerekHunziker value for what ?

Comment: The value of your og:title meta tag, but of course

Comment: @DerekHunziker no it has a value !! I've just tried it

Comment: Listen to Derek. The og:title tag is empty on that site. <meta property="og:title" content=""/>

Comment: @DerekHunziker  also the <title></title> empty ??

Comment: Why you want to $_GET['p'] ??? You have to put a real Value... Get Can't have a value when your site is loading for the first time

Comment: Btw, GET parameters are not “session values” in the sense this term is commonly used in PHP – $_SESSION is something completely different from $_GET …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a default value

```
if(!isset($_GET['p'])){
$value = 'default value';
}else{
$value = $_GET['p'];
}

<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $value; ?>"/>
```

The default value will be there on your home page OG

Comment: but why always $_GET['p'] is empty ?!

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course he doesn't get filled in http://www.palestinianz.com/ because the og:title is being filled with the p argument in the URL (GET['p']). If I visit http://www.palestinianz.com/?p=Tivie, the og:title gets filled with "Tivie".

If that is the desired effect then point the debugger to a person page. http://www.palestinianz.com/?p=Alex-Atalla or something.

EDIT:
I think I understand what you're trying to do.
If you don't mind my suggestion...

change your code to this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php print (isset($_GET['p'])) ? $_GET['p'] : 'They Are Palestinians'; ?>"/>
```

Then read about [Apache Mod Rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: yes but the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpalestinianz.com%2F%3Fpage%3Dperson%26p%3DEdward-Said says there is no value for og:title till I have p in the URL

Comment: but why always $_GET['p'] is empty ?!

Comment: $_GET['p'] is the p=something in the url. If there is no p=something in the url, $_GET['p'] is empty!

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this problem....???I know what's happening bit can't fix it...its wreckin me head...,